# Laravel 5.3 production migrate PDOException

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I get the following error `[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name o
  r service not known`

I first tried restarting mysql, which failed. I then added `[mysqld]` at the top of `my.cnf` file. This file is basically empty - only has two lines in.
This fixed the mysql restart issue, but didn't solve migration. mysql running fine now. I can connect doing mysql -h localhost -u -p database

I changed binding in `mysqld.cnf` to 0.0.0.0, this didn't work either.
My Laravel database has no tables, not even a migration table, is this correct? I pushed my dev project to production with git.
I also changed the host in .env to 127.0.0.1

I also added `unix_socket` `=>` `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` to `database.php` - didn't help either.

I run nginx on production. Please advise how to fix migration.
Port 3306 is listed as a listening port.
However, going to the production server IP in the browser like http://ip:3306 gives some funny characters and "Got packets out of order"

Comment: If MySQL is not running, it's clear why Laravel cannot connect to it, isn't it? :-?

Comment: It is running - I explained in first bit how I got it running."This fixed mysql restart issue"

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you shared that information because it was part of the question. So, MySQL is up and running and you can connect from other clients, but Laravel complaints about the host name being unknown? Have you checked what host it's trying to connect to?

Comment: Thanks. I can connect from the command line on the prod server. How do I check what host it tries to connect to? Also updated question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Laravel user. I presume it uses some kind of configuration file where you type the database details (host, username and password) but I can't tell you what file it is. Perhaps it's mentioned in the documentation. As about your edit, MySQL is not a web server, you cannot use a browser to connect to MySQL.

Comment: It's in the .env file yes. I checked the details many times. I re-installed the whole server and it's working now. This time I skipped this line: `sudo mysql_secure_installation`. Maybe that's why.